# Looping through class with multiple ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class:

```
public class ClassA 
{
   string Field1;
   int Field2;
   ObservableCollection<ClassB> col1;
   ObservableCollection<ClassC> col2;
   ObservableCollection<ClassD> col3;
   ObservableCollection<ClassE> col4;
   ObservableCollection<ClassF> col5;
   // ...
}
```

In my application, when the user hits save I need to loop through this class and perform actions with each of its members.

I can use reflection to go through the normal fields, but not sure how to:

1. get each of the collections
2. identify what type it holds
3. loop its items and cast each collection item to its Type so can work with it.

Background:
I have multiple datagrids on a wpf app, with the class structure above being the viewModel datacontext.

When user hits save I need to do save each item in the viewmodel to its own relevant table in the database via stored procs.

Once I have the a collection I need to test IF "is a class b" or IF "is a class C" and then use the particular method on it, with that method receiving the actual Type.

Would be much cleaner than hardcoding the class.

Comment: The first two are pretty easy, the third is going to be your issue. How do you want to "work with it"? do each of the classes contained in the collections implement a common interface?

Comment: *"loop its items and cast each collection item to its Type so can work with it."* Which means you need to know something about the type at coding time (otherwise how do you know the methods/properties). Do the classes derive from some common base type? What do you need to do with the classes, serialize them?

Comment: Hi Ron. Have upated the post to  add more info. The classes do not derive from a base type at the moment as they aren't in common..

Comment: if you are working with database, I suggest you go with [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). It can easily map a database model into any kind of custom class, given mapping customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection can be used to interrogate a type hierarchy at run-time, however this quickly becomes painful if you're trying to do so with generics, more so if you think you can access the type at runtime as you would at compile-time.

The code below demonstrates the principal behind (1) and (2) in your question. (3) is harder to answer without more detail on how you wish to use the generic types contained in each `ObservableCollection`.

```
var instance = new ClassA();
var fields = instance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
foreach(var field in fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Field name: {0}. Type:{1} IsGeneric:{2}", field.Name, field.FieldType.Name, field.FieldType.IsGenericType);
    if(field.FieldType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var genericArgs = field.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments;
        foreach(var genericArg in genericArgs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\tGenericArg Type:{0}", genericArg.Name);
        }
    }

}
```

Live demo: http://rextester.com/AJVS85556